# ./fastboot: No such file or directory

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, fastboot

I've struggled with this for awhile! I'm beating my head against the wall.

I am trying to run fastboot (android-linux-tools/platform-tools/fastboot) and I am getting a `No such file or directory` message.

I am on ubuntu 12.04 x64. I am not new to linux, I'm baffled.

```
$ cd ~/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
$ ./fastboot
-bash: ./fastboot: No such file or directory
$ ./adb devices
-bash: ./adb: No such file or directory
$ ls -la
...
-rwxrwxr-x  1 nick nick   159644 Apr 16 21:10 adb
...
-rwxrwxr-x  1 nick nick   149928 Aug 16 21:10 fastboot
...
```

Comment: Your commands do not make sense. `cd` cannot return `./adb: No such file or directory`. Please post the right commands.

Comment: you're right, copy paste messed up... updated

Comment: This is weird, but can you run successfully this command `~/android-linux-tools/tools/android`? If you can, you may want to update to the latest version. Or, maybe you can simply download the latest version, and see whether the problem still exists.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19524010/1778421

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is this a new machine where you have just downloaded the SDK? Since you are running a 64-bit distribution, check whether you have [installed the ia32-libs package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html) needed for the SDK executables to work:

> sudo apt-get install ia32-libs

Comment: thank you! not sure if this was on the old version of their website, but I'm glad its there now!

Answer (score 0):

Try with su.

I had the same problem with .android directory and even with the ls command I could not see it(even after su). After su I could cd in the directory