# linux ubuntu - initial setting for android development

Tags: android, installation, adb

I am new in android development and am using linux ubuntu plateform.

When i set path to android-sdk in eclipse or I create a new android project I get this error:

```
failed to parse the output of 'adb version':

adb version failed:

path_to/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb: error while loading shared libraries:
 libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I am using latest adt-bundle from android site.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19524010/1778421

Answer (score 0):

You lack 32-bit libraries for ADB. You need to run the following commands in your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6
```

Comment: the error - cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. Is it the problem coz i am not the admin of my computer ?

Comment: No, it is because the lib32stdc++6 package is not installed.

Comment: i installed as you said but still same problem!

Comment: That's really strange. I hope someone else can shed some light into your problem.