# jenkins build fail with adb not found

Tags: android, jenkins, adb

I was trying to build my android studio project set up with jenkins, I get into an error adb not found ,, i am using the gradle emulator plugin.

```
 java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb": error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:803)
at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:381)
at hudson.plugins.android_emulator.AndroidEmulator.doSetUp(AndroidEmulator.java:304)
at hudson.plugins.android_emulator.AndroidEmulator.setUp(AndroidEmulator.java:263)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:154)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:536)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:374)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
... 12 more
```

Finished: FAILURE

```
$ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/tools/android list target
[android] Using Android SDK: /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk
$ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
```

it seems like jenkins is using the android sdk folder, so I don't think its a path related issue

in local mechine I've had this same error before ( the solution was to install a collection of libraries)

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

but i'm not sure how to do it in jenkins..

any thoughts?
thanks

Comment: Did you specify the path to your Android home on Jenkins?

Comment: Log in to that machine and run the `apt-get` command.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19524010/1778421

Answer (score 4):

you should configure ANDROID_HOME in jenkins

1. open jenkins
2. login with admin
3. click manage jenkins on left menu
4. click configure system
5. set ANDROID_HOME

[image]

Comment: That has been set and its using it also I think,I 've updated the question

Comment: @P-RAD Was your issue resolved? How did you get through this?

Comment: I'm sorry. I haven't actually. Project which I was working on got dropped

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your `adb path` in the Jenkins in the `execute shell` in the Build step.

`export Path = "which ever your path is"`

you can get your adb path with `which adb`