# Application not running on Eclipse with ADT bundle

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to develop an application on Eclipse with ADT bundle, but when I try to run my application it shows the following error:

> [2015-09-08 21:27:53 - gpio] /home/tejvir/android-sdks/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libgcc_s.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

What should be done in this situation?

I tried the solutions in the other question mentioned above but I have encountered the following errors in it :

```
sudo apt-get -qqy install libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I have also tried the other solution given on the same link and even that has not provided me with the solution. 
Following are the errors I have encountered while trying the solution:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
lib32ncurses5 is already the newest version.
libc6-i386 is already the newest version.
libc6-i386 set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

     The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     lib32gcc1 : Depends: gcc-4.9-base (= 4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1) but 4.9.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
     lib32stdc++6 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
     E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I am kinda stuck here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make Android's aapt and adb work on 64-bit Ubuntu without ia32-libs (works for versions 12, 13 and 14)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523502/how-to-make-androids-aapt-and-adb-work-on-64-bit-ubuntu-without-ia32-libs-work)

Comment: Please check the edits made..

Comment: @AlexP. I still dont have an answer... What do you suggest...

Answer (score 0):

I have actually solved my question with some expert help.

I have explained the problem above but the real problem was that my gcc was having some issues regarding which version to run and the versions that i had installed were not for my distribution i.e. Ubuntu 14.04. And in addition to that adb that comes for linux has been updated to run with 32 bit architecture but not with 64 bit architecture. That is the reason why my adb is showing errors for files that already exist in my system.

Now to remove these errors i first needed to correct my gcc and then work my way up in order to install all the required 32 bit architecture libraries.

So now i will explain how i solved my problem. 
NOTE: This worked for my computer and i am not sure if it is going to work on every PC. But i think it will work on almost all PCs.

Let's Go.

Run the following commands.

```
1. sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8base=4.8.2-19ubuntu1
```

Now if you are getting the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies: 

  indicator-bluetooth : Depends: unity-control-center but it is not going to be installed or 

  gnome-control-center but it is not going to be installed or 

  ubuntu-system-settings but it is not going to be installed 

  libdee-1.0-4 : Depends: libicu52 (>= 52~m1-1~) but it is not going to be installed         

  system-image-dbus : Depends: system-image-common (= 2.2-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed 

 E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Next run the following command:

```
 2. apt-cache policy libicu52 libdee-1.0-4 system-image-dbus system-image-common

Now check if you are getting the following output:

 libicu52:
     Installed: 52.1-3ubuntu0.3
     Candidate: 52.1-3ubuntu0.3 
     Version table:
      *** 52.1-3ubuntu0.3 0
           500 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
            100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
      52.1-3 0
            500 in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/main amd64 Packages
 libdee-1.0-4:
     Installed: 1.2.7+14.04.20140324-0ubuntu1
     Candidate: 1.2.7+14.04.20140324-0ubuntu1
     Version table:
     *** 1.2.7+14.04.20140324-0ubuntu1 0
         500 in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/main amd64 Packages
         100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 system-image-dbus:
     Installed: (none)
     Candidate: 2.2-0ubuntu1
     Version table:
     2.2-0ubuntu1 0
```

If you are with me up to this point. Then this means that you have really messed up your system. From this point onwards we will first try to fix our system.

Run the following two commands:

```
3. sudo sed -i.bak 's/http:\/\/in./http:\/\//' /etc/apt/sources.list

4. sudo apt-get update
```

After this is done.

Execute these two commands

```
  5. sudo apt-get install system-image-dbus

  6. sudo apt-get install system-image-common
```

Now after this run the following command:

```
  7. sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8-base=4.8.2-19ubuntu1
```

If this file gets installed on your PC without any problem then you are basically done. You don't need to go ahead with this. But if your system prints out the following error

```
  The following packages have unmet dependencies:

   indicator-bluetooth : Depends: unity-control-center but it is not going to be installed or

   gnome-control-center but it is not going to be installed or

   ubuntu-system-settings but it is not going to be installed

    libdee-1.0-4 : Depends: libicu52 (>= 52~m1-1~) but it is not going to be installed

    E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

If you encounter this error then run the following command.

  8. sudo apt-get install --reinstall libicu52

  9.  sudo apt-get install libdee-1.0-4

  10. sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Now this last command might take some time depending on your internet connection.

After this is done... Follow the below sets of instructions and you are done.

1. Start <kbd>Software & Updates</kbd>
2. Select the tab <kbd>Updates</kbd>
3. Select <kbd>Recommended updates (trusty-updates)</kbd> (In my screenshot it's vivid-updates, but that's just an example)

   [image]

   And click <kbd>Close</kbd>
4. Click <kbd>Reload</kbd> in this dialog

   [image]
5. Now upgrade your system (again **;)**)

   ```
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```
6. And install

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
   ```

And after this you are good to go.. :)

Thank You