# ADB not responding. If you'd like to retry, then please manually kill "adb" and click 'Restart' in Ubuntu

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I am facing this on my ubuntu(14.04) while running app. I am getting pop up with the message "ADB not responding. If you'd like to retry, then please manually kill "adb" and click 'Restart'".
I have installed : sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32z1-dev lib32stdc++6
and i have also tried sudo adb kill-server and sudo adb start-server .
I have already spent more then 4 hrs for this problem . How to fix this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Android's aapt and adb work on 64-bit Ubuntu without ia32-libs (works for versions 12, 13 and 14)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523502/how-to-make-androids-aapt-and-adb-work-on-64-bit-ubuntu-without-ia32-libs-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me in (Ubuntu 14.04):

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32z1-dev lib32stdc++6
```

Comment: after install what else need to do ? i just restarted android studio and run command sudo adb kill-server and sudo adb start-server

Comment: yes , i have resolved the issue. I need to restart my system.